# How to delete CKShare?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

User A shares share URL with User B. User B doesn't want to accept the share URL. As I understand, User B has to delete CKShare from Shared Database. So how does User B delete the CKShare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple. Just had to add CKShare.RecordID as recordID to be deleted to CKModifyRecordOperation operation.

Comment: Is the CKShare.recordID the same as the CKRecord.recordID of the root record?

Comment: When I delete the shares using CKModifyRecordsOperation and record ids of the shares, the root records don't get deleted. How do I make the root records get deleted when I delete the share?

Comment: You don't delete the root record.